# How to catch for client.connect() in node-postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, error-handling, node-postgres

try/catch does not work for client.connect():

```
const { Pool, Client } = require('pg')
try {
  const client = new Client(config)
  client.connect()
} catch (er) {
  console.log('error')
}
```

Error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user '...'
```

How can I change the async `connect()` to sync for try/catch?

Comment: await it in an async function, or use .then and .catch instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`connect()` without a callback function returns a promise, which you could apply the `.catch` method to:

```js
client
  .connect()
  .then(() => console.log('connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('connection error', err.stack))
```